# Human Detection using edge detection

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, matlab-cvst

I am trying to detect exact silhouette of human body in this [dataset](http://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~labimage/Dataset/) using background subtraction. After doing some thresholding I was getting split blobs so I looked at this tutorial by [Steve](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2010/09/07/almost-connected-component-labeling/) but now I am getting blob other that human body as shown below

So here is the original

[image]

After Subtracting it from background, background was considered as the first frame of the video, so after subtracting it from orignal image I get the following image

[image]

so I did basic thresholding and I get the following image, which is split from further areas

[image]

and using Steve's method I get this

[image]

But this contains a lot of area which is not a part of human body, any suggestion if somehow or using edges I can get good blob of human body.

**EDIT**

As *@lennon310* asked me to upload color image so here it is

[image]

and as *@NKN* asked me to upload edge information of the same image so here it is

[image]

Comment: is your original image gray or rgb?

Comment: its rgb, I converted it in to gray-scale.

Comment: I guess the problem arises from the thresholding, can you give a comparison with edge command in MATLAB and methods like, canny or sobel.

Comment: can you upload the raw rgb as well?

Comment: Please check the updated version of question.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of literally subtracting the background, try using the `vision.ForegroundDetector` object, which is part of the Computer Vision System Toolbox.  It implements the mixture-of-gaussians adaptive background modeling, and it may give you a cleaner segmentation.

Having said that, it is very unlikely that you will get the "exact" silhouette. Some error is inevitable.

Answer (score 1):

In your result image, you have tow types of black regions. one is moving and the other is stationary.
So when you you want to fill the human body, you have to choose only the moving region, for this purpose, I suggest to segment your image by adding optical flow technique to know where the moving regions are. 
This is an interesting tutorial doing what you need to do:
http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_video/py_lucas_kanade/py_lucas_kanade.html